# Printing JSON like console.log prints it in Node.js

Tags: json, node.js, pretty-print

Wondering if it's possible to print JSON like Node.js prints it out. If there is some standard module or something to do that.

[image]

It has the spacing between keys, and when it's too long it goes onto a new line, etc. The coloring would be a bonus.

`JSON.stringify(object, null, 2)` pretty prints the JSON, wondering if there is something more hidden in there, or any standards, for doing it like Node.js does. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This seems to be achievable by using [`util.inspect()`](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_inspect_object_options):

```
const util = require('util');

const testJson = `{
    "id": "0001",
    "type": "donut",
    "name": "Cake",
    "ppu": 0.55,
    "batters":
        {
            "batter":
                [
                    { "id": "1001", "type": "Regular" },
                    { "id": "1002", "type": "Chocolate" },
                    { "id": "1003", "type": "Blueberry" },
                    { "id": "1004", "type": "Devil's Food" }
                ]
        },
    "topping":
        [
            { "id": "5001", "type": "None" },
            { "id": "5002", "type": "Glazed" },
            { "id": "5005", "type": "Sugar" },
            { "id": "5007", "type": "Powdered Sugar" },
            { "id": "5006", "type": "Chocolate with Sprinkles" },
            { "id": "5003", "type": "Chocolate" },
            { "id": "5004", "type": "Maple" }
        ]
}`

x = JSON.parse(testJson);
x.x = x;
console.log(util.inspect(x, { colors: true }));
```

[image: with depth=2]

The options object takes a parameter called `depth` that determines how deep it will recurse. The default value is 2. If I increase it to 3:

```
console.log(util.inspect(x, { colors: true, depth: 3 }));
```

I get the following:

[image: with depth=3]

To make it recurse indefinitely pass `depth: null`. The default value seems to be 2 in the node cli as well.

Comment: It is equivalent to `console.dir(obj, options)`